# Firebase Database: How to save a list of friends per user?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Every User has a list of items with the same key like for example friends.
I know this example is wrong because every key should be unique. 
How can I do that in the JSON Format?

```
 {
  "users" : {
    "jmEcUjPaXVXHdsaddasdFrh1" : {
      "Name" : "John",
      "friends" : {
        "Name" : "Peter",
        "Name" : "Bob",
        "Name" : "Lisa"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried this but I am not sure if this is a good solution

```
{
  "users" : {
    "jmEcUjPaXVXHdsaddasdFrh1" : {
      "Name" : "John",
      "friends" : {
        "Peter" : "true",
        "Bob" : "true",
        "Lisa" : "true"
      }
    }
  }
}


#askFirebase
```

Comment: You've included a picture of JSON in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen your welcome ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is to store array of friends.

```
{
  "users": {
    "jmEcU..." : {
      "Name" : "John",
      "friends" : [
        "Peter",
        "Bob",
        "Lisa"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However, there are some concurrency issues with using an array with distributed data. I'll suggest you really read [this post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) to get an understanding of the implications of using an array with Firebase Database.

If after going through [this section of the post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html#good-use-cases-for-storing-data-in-arrays), and you determine you cannot use an array, here are a couple of suggestions for a new structure

Structure 1: Use the friend's name as the key. You can use anything as the value, as long as it is not `null`. You can loop through all the children of `friends` and get the keys.

**Pro:** Very quick to find out if a user is friends with another user - `/users/{id}/friends/{name} exists`

**Con:** Each friend's name has to be unique

```
{
  "users": {
    "jmEcU..." : {
      "Name" : "John",
      "friends" : {
        "Peter" : true,
        "Bob" : true,
        "Lisa" : true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Structure 2: Using Firebase's `Push` to create unique ids and use as keys, with the friends' names as values. You can loop through all the children of `friends` and get the values.

**Pro:** Friends names don't have to be unique

```
{
  "users": {
    "jmEcU..." : {
      "Name" : "John",
      "friends" : {
        "-JGnfnf..." : "Peter",
        "-JGnfoi.." : "Bob",
        "-JGnfuy.." : "Lisa"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If what you need from the friend is more than just the name, I would advice to store the friend's user-id, instead of an object representing the friend's details. If your user-ids are unique, this should solve the con of Structure 1, and make it the better of the two options.

Answer (score 1):

Try this structure:

```
  "users" : {
    "{user_1}" : {
      "email" : "geek@live.com",
      "firstName" : "Geek",
      "friends" : {
        "{user_2}" : {
          "status" : "pending",
          "with" : {
             "firstName" : "Anna", 
            "profileImage" : "http://..."
          }
        }
      }
    } ,
    "{user_2}" : {
      "email" : "anna@live.com",
      "firstName" : "Anna",
      "friends" : {
        "{user_1}" : {
          "status" : "pending",
          "with" : {
             "firstName" : "Geek",
             "profileImage" : "https:..."
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It is not the way to go, it look ok but when you want to show information like email and first name of the user you will bring along all the friends info as well.

Would be better to create another node only with friends outside of the users node.